# Encoding problem with latexdiff

Tags: input-encodings, latexdiff

After discovering [`latexdiff`](http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=3579), I wanted to give it a try and promptly ran into what seems to be an enconding issue.
Consider these two very simple example files (without special characters):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
Hello StackExchange.
This is \LaTeX.
\end{document}
```

And the second:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
Hallo StackExchange.
Hier ist \LaTeX.
\end{document}
```

Then I run the following command (utf8 should be the default encoding anyway):

```
latexdiff -e utf8 helloSE1.tex helloSE2.tex > helloSEdiff.tex
```

The output file is produced correctly, though I get a lot of warnings like:

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex;
```

First, when I try opening `helloSEdiff.tex` with Texmaker, it's telling me that this file cannot be read with the default encoding, and I need to choose UTF-16.
Thus, I can open it, but when I run `pdflatex` on it, it just gives:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \^^@
        d^^@o^^@c^^@u^^@m^^@e^^@n^^@t^^@c^^@l^^@a^^@s^^@s^^@{^^@s^^@c^^@r^^@...
```

I am using TeX Live 2016, if this matters.

Comment: I get an output but also all the warnings. Imho the problem is with the perl version. If I force latexdiff to use my external perl (which is older than the one in texlive) with `set TEXLIVE_WINDOWS_TRY_EXTERNAL_PERL=1` the warnings disappear.

Comment: The warnings indeed arise from a change in syntax in the newer perl version. They have been fixed in the development version of latexdiff (on github); mostly they are removed already in release 1.2.0 but a few intances remain and will be fixed in release 1.3.0 (not yet released). These warnings can be ignored, and they have nothing to do with your encoding problems. Why latexdiff would output utf-16 instead of specifying utf-8 is beyond me. Maybe try `-e ascii` or `-e utf-8-strict`

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, I can confirm that the warnings still appear; however, the compilation of the `*diff.tex` file and the resulting PDF all work as expected. Following versions used:
`This is LATEXDIFF 1.1.1  (Algorithm::Diff 1.15 fast, Perl v5.22.1)`
So this seems to be a Windows-specific problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same encoding-issue on my windows machine. I circumvented the issue by opening the tex-file with notepad++, going to the `Encoding tab` > `Encode in UTF-8-BOM` and then saving the file. I was then able to open and compile the tex-file in TexMaker.

Comment: You save my day