# latexdiff encoding issue

Tags: miktex, windows, input-encodings, latexdiff, perl

I got the exact same problem as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390717/what-output-encoding-does-latexdiff-use/507805#507805) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360763/encoding-problem-with-latexdiff):

- umlauts are translated into strange characters; the output file does not compile
- the output file is UCS2-Little-Endian encoded (according to Notepad++)
- adding `--encoding=utf8` or `--encoding=utf-8-strict` changes nothing; problems appear already if I add e.g. an "ä" to the document body of one of those example documents.
- if I (1) replace all special characters in the input files with ASCII characters and (2) change the encoding of the output file to UTF8, it will compile.

I'm using MiKTeX with TeXstudio on a Windows 10 system.

Is there a now a known solution to this problem?

Comment: This isn't answer to your question, but I would really like to know the answer because I am having exactly the same thing happening. 

I ended up having to use https://3142.nl/latex-diff/ because, just like you, latexdiff was generating the weiredest characters for me on windows - even when everything was set to `utf-8` and I had used `dos2unix` on all the input files.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the solution was to use plain old `cmd` instead of Powershell. It seems that powershell uses UTF-16, which messes up the encoding of the output.